# Need $2 and $1 to be interpreted using substitution

Tags: perl, substitution

So my problem is that im trying to replace all occurrences of a certain character to another character.

It is used like so: "Usage: ./swap.pl 'input' 'output'";

Where input is the string to change all occurrences of and output is the character it is being changed to.

My script needs to be able to recognize regex as well.

The problem occurs with this case ([aeiou][aeiou]) to '$2$1' Meaning flip the characters in the capture group.

Ive tried:

1.Pulling out the string, splitting it and changing their positions, but it saves the first occurrence and uses it for the rest of the matches instead of updating every time.

2. Using a substitution (s///) but it doesn't interpret the $1$2 as their values. Apparently there is a eval(qq{}) expression I can use, but it doesn't seem to work in the substitution operator.
3. Using tr//; but that didn't really do anything.
4. I tried to evaluate the string, then create a new string by saving the characters in the swapped order but that didn't seem to work either.

Im kind of stuck and dont know how to proceed. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
my $size = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($size != 2)
{
        print STDERR "Usage: ./swap.pl 'input' 'output'";
        exit 1;
}

while(<STDIN>)
{

        $_ =~ s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/ig;
        print $_;

}
```

Most cases work great:

"Isaac Newton and the Apple | "./swap.pl 'p' 'q'" would output "Isaac Newton and the Aqqle"

But cases like ([l])([e]) are being treated as;

"Isaac Newton and the Apple | "./swap.pl '([l])([e])' '$2$1'" would output "Isaac Newton and the App$2$1" Whereas it should output "Isaac Newton and the Appel"

EDIT2:
I tried going back to #2 and that command seems to be working, however it only captures the first capture group and stores it whereas I need it to capture every new occurring group.

EDIT3:

After grueling over it a bit, I figured it out! Capture groups mean different things depending on where you use them. If I used them in an if statement, they just capture the first group and remain the same

If used in a substitution however, the capture group updates every time you encounter a match. I just checked to see if the input was a regex.

Comment: What's wrong with `perl -wE'$_=q(abxy); s/([ab]+)([xy]+)/$2$1/; say'`?

Comment: I believe if im reading your command correctly, that its only looking to swap characters that are next to each other, which is a subset of my problem.

Comment: It's just a simple example, of swapping the capture groups. It is not clear to me what the problem is -- you state that you want to swap individual characters inside a capture group (of only two chars), but the (only) answer assumes that you in fact mean two capture groups and you didn't correct that in the comment. I'd suggest that you edit the question with an example of an input string and what the output should be.

Comment: @user1234700: *"swap characters that are next to each other ... is a subset of my problem"* Well, I answered the question you asked, if your requirements are broader you need to say so in the question. See also [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added better clarification to my entire problem, my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

In the regex `([aeiou][aeiou])`, you only have one capture group, so `$2` will not contain anything, you probably meant `([aeiou])([aeiou])`.

As for having the replacement be interpreted as code, you could use the [`/ee` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/_PATTERN_/_REPLACEMENT_/msixpodualngcer), which means "evaluate the right side as a string, then [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) the result." One thing to be careful with is that `eval` allows for the execution of arbitrary code, so as long as this is just a lab exercise it's fine, but it's something to be very careful with in a multi-user environment.
(I'd apply a similar warning to user-supplied regexes, even if the execution of user-supplied code is normally [restricted](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'eval'-mode) there.)

Because the string in the replacement will be evaluated as a Perl expression, we need to add the dot concatenation operator between the two strings, since `$2$1` would not be valid.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $regex = '([aeiou])([aeiou])';
my $subst = '$2.$1';
my $str = 'xeOyAuz';
$str =~ s/$regex/$subst/eeig;
print "<$str>\n";                  # prints "<xOeyuAz>"
```

Comment: I think what I was missing was the /ee modifier. After having added it, im getting a "Scalar found where operator expected" with iterating evals. Apparently this is expected behavior. Do I need to add a '.' or replace the $ with \ (\2.\1) in order to fix this?

Comment: I don't see why you need `/ee`.  Isn't `s/(.)(.)/$2$1/` (swaps captures) what is needed?

Comment: The problem itself is tricky. Here is the way I understand it:

If the input contains ([aeiou])([aeiou]) then swap the characters $2$1.

If the input is some word, then swap every character 'e' with '@'.

I dont know how to separate these two cases. Im given test cases where both of these scenarios exist, so the output is coming out wrong.

I feel as though Perl has the capability to do both with one command but I think im missing something.

Comment: @user1234700: *"Do I need to add a '.'"* I already answered that above! `eval` needs valid Perl source code, `$2$1` would not be valid Perl - `"$2$1"` or `$2.$1` would be.

Comment: @zdim: The way I understood the question was that both the search and replacement part are coming from strings; in the code shown it's `s/$ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]/ig`.

Comment: @user1234700: *"then swap every character 'e' with '@'"* This is another new requirement that you didn't state in the question, so of course we can't help you with it (yet)! *"I feel as though Perl has the capability to do both with one command"* Probably, but if you want help with that you'll have to ask properly, meaning giving all the requirements, sample inputs with expected outputs, the code you tried, etc., in the question.

Comment: Sure, and the question is rather unclear and your take is reasonable. Still, there is no need for `/ee` in order to just swap captures -- `s/../$2.$1/ee` is the same as `s/../$2$1/` (unless a capture contains a variable name like `$x`, or code, which need be evaluated).